# What information is leaked in a TLS/SSL handshake (certs etc)?

Tags: security, ssl, cryptography, certificate

I want to understand what kind of information TLS leaks during a handshake to a passive interceptor, in particular:

1. Is the client certificate (if any) sent in cleartext?
2. Is the server certificate sent in cleartext?
3. If SNI (Server Name indication) is used, is that sent in cleartext?
4. Any other revealing information sent.

If they are sent in cleartext, are there any workarounds which can force them to be in ciphertext?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and is more suitable for security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the client certificate (if any) sent in cleartext?

If it's sent at all, yes, unless this is a rehandshake.

> Is the server certificate sent in cleartext?

Yes, unless this is a rehandshake.

> If SNI (Server Name indication) is used, is that sent in cleartext?

Yes, unless this is a rehandshake.

> Any other revealing information sent.

The IP addresses and port numbers of both parties are visible in the clear, as are their current TCP receive windows and sequence numbers.

> If they are sent in cleartext, are there any workarounds which can force them to be in ciphertext?

Only by performing a prior handshake, which is an infinite regress.

There's nothing private in a certificate. What are you trying to protect exactly?

Comment: One possible reason to want to hide the client certificate data is when it contains the actual user name (e.g. "`CN=John Smith`"). This can be considered leaking personal data, when logging into a service that is meant to be confidential, where anonymity with respect to 3rd parties matters. In this case re-negotiation helps. This is generally not a problem for the server certificate.

Comment: Another possible reason is to hide domain from country's internet firewall.